# How do I turn a clippath into vectors?

Tags: inkscape, svg, clipping-mask

I am new to inkscapeand have the following problem:

I need to generate an svg image which does not contain a clippath - only vectors.
But I used a clip mask to create a shaped pattern from an outline and a vector pattern (imagine a hatched circle).

Now I try to turn this into just vectors without the clippath.
I tried to use path menu (turn object into path etc.) without success.

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: A clipPath is actually an SVG vector element, so it's technically not correct to say it isn't vector. Unfortunately, you can't expand something that has been clipped to pure outlines, and essentially have the clipping path cut out the pattern. You'll need to use a different technique.

To achieve what you want, you could do the following:

1. Create a pattern made of strokes, and outline them using using *Path > Stroke to path* (or just skip this step if your pattern is already filled outlines)
2. Do *Path > Combine*, to make the pattern a combined path.
3. Place a circle on top
4. Select both pattern and circle and do *Path > Intersection*

The circle will cut out the pattern where it intersects.

[image]

Comment: thanx. it works!